# How to Make a Change to an Existing Page Go Live at a Particular Point in Time

Tags: entry

In Craft, is it possible to make an edit to an already existing (live) page but be able to set a particular point in time that you want to change to go live?

I know that you can set the post date and time for when you're implementing a new page but curious if there's a similar capability for implementing a change to that page after it's already live.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, there is not. I've dealt with this before and I actually created 2 pages, one with the future post date, and one with an expiry date. And so the future page will become active over the page that will expire, simulating the requested functionality (although this is not the preferred method, I concur)

Comment: Thanks, Bob! Good suggestion. Would be great to see this as a feature in future versions of Craft.